# Determine the $P(1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, polynomials

> $P(x)$ is a polynomial function,
>
> $$P(x)-P'(x) = 2x^2-8x$$
>
> Determine the $P(1)$

I've tried to solve the polynomial for $0$

$$P(0) = 2x^2-8x$$

Here we get

$$x = \{4 , 0\}$$

However, I believe that I've gone wrong so far.

Comment: Have you copied the problem exactly as it was written?  As written, it is not possible to solve (there is not enough information to determine $P(1)$).  In any case, you seem very badly confused about what the problem means.  I would suggest you try reading it carefully and make sure you understand it before anything else.

Comment: How to solve this problem using differential equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *locally nilpotent* linear operator on a vector space $V$ (not necessarily finite-dimensional) over a field $\mathbb{K}$ is a linear operator $N:V\to V$ such that, for each $v\in V$, there exists a nonnegative integer $r_v$ depending on $v$ such that
$$N^{r_v}(v)=0_V\,.$$  Here, $N^0:=\text{id}_V$.  For such a linear operator $N$, the linear operator $\text{id}_V-N:V\to V$ is bijective.  To show this, we exhibit the inverse of $\text{id}_V-N$ as $i(N):=\sum\limits_{r=0}^\infty\,N^r$.  This linear operator $i(N):V\to V$ is well defined because $N$ is locally nilpotent.    It is clear that
$$\left(\text{id}_V-N\right)\,i(N)=\text{id}_V=i(N)\,\left(\text{id}_V-N\right)\,.$$

Now, the derivative operator $D$, $Df:=f'$, is a locally nilpotent operator on the vector space $\mathbb{K}[X]$ of polynomials in variable $X$ over an arbitrary field $\mathbb{K}$, namely, for each $f(x)\in\mathbb{K}[x]$,
$$D^{\deg(f)+1}f\equiv0\text{ for }f\not\equiv0\,,\text{ and }D^0f\equiv 0\text{ for }f\equiv0\,.$$
By convention, $D^0$ denotes the identity operator $I$.

> Now, we go back to the problem.  Observe that $$\big((I-D)\,P\big)(X)=P(X)-P'(X)=2X^2-8X\,.$$  By the paragraph above, $$\begin{align}P(X)&=(I-D)^{-1}\,\left(2X^2-8X\right)=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\,D^r\left(2X^2-8X\right)\\ &=(2X^2-8X)+(4X-8)+4=2X^2-4X-4\,.\end{align}$$  That is, $P(1)=-6$.

Answer (score 2):

as mentioned in the comment by @mfl that the polynomial must have degree two because if we take P as degree n polynomial then  P-P' also has degree n thus n=2 because the right side polynomial is of degree 2.

you can solve it by taking a  degree two polynomial $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

I got $b=c$ and $a=2$ and $2a-b=8$

thus $$P(x)=2x^2-4x-4$$
thus $$P(1)=2-4-4=-6$$
$\hspace{20pt}$

**Here is method two if want to solve this by differential equations**

this is of the form  $$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}-y=8x-2x^2$$

$$P(x)=-1 \space and \space  Q(x)=8x-2x^2$$
in this type of differential equations, we multiply the equation by integrating factor

integrating factor $$R(x)=e^{\int P(x) dx}$$

thus $$R(x)=e^{\int -1 dx}=e^{-x}$$

multiply by $R(x)$
$$e^{-x}\frac{dy}{dx}-e^{-x}y=e^{-x}(8x-2x^2)$$
$$\frac{d(e^{-x}y)}{dx}=e^{-x}(8x-2x^2)$$
$$e^{-x}y=\int e^{-x}(8x-2x^2) dx $$

apply integration by part two times on the right side you will get

$$e^{-x}y= e^{-x}(2x^2-4x-4) + C$$

thus $$y= 2x^2-4x-4+ C *e^x$$
since P is a polynomial C must be zero

Comment: Note that $P$ must have degree two.

Comment: @taritgoswami No. If $P$ has degree $n$ then $P'$ has degree $n-1.$ Thus $P-P'$ has degree $n.$ So we have $n=2.$

Comment: I don't know why am I being downvoted?

Comment: Don't worry. This happens. I have upvoted. I didn't check your answer but it is the correct way to solve the question.

Comment: I edited the solution and solved the question using differential equation hope this is fine

Comment: @James  The constant $C$ should be outside the parenthesis.  That is, $$\exp(-x)\,y=\exp(-x)\,\big(2x^2-4x-4\big)+C$$ and $$y=2x^2-4x-4+C\exp(x)\,.$$  Since $P$ is a polynomial, $C$ must be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P(x)$ be any n degree polynomial
$$P(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2x^2 + ... + a_nx^n$$

Given that:

$$P(x)-P'(x) = 2x^2-8x$$
$$\implies a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2 + ... a_nx^n - (a_1+2a_2x + ...na_nx^{n-1} )= 2x^2 - 8x$$

$$(a_0-a_1) + (a_1-2a_2)x + (a_2 - 3a_3)x^2 + .... = 2x^2 - 8x$$

Now the r.h.s and l.h.s are two polynomials that are equal for all values of $x$. Therefore they must be equivalent. You should be able to proceed now..

Cheers!